# Did Kronecker say that set theory is not mathematics?

Tags: mathematics, reference-request, set-theory, quote, kronecker

I have frequently come across Kronecker's statement about set theory:

> I don't know what predominates in Cantor's theory - philosophy or theology, but I am sure that there is no mathematics there.

It is quoted in Wikipedia. Google shows over 400 hits. But I have never seen a hint to the original source.

It need not be explained that Kronecker had a very negative attitude toward set theory. Did Kronecker say so? And if yes, where and when?

Comment: For many references to Kronecker's opposition to Cantorian set theory, you can see José Ferreirós, [Labyrinth of Thought: A History of Set Theory and Its Role in Modern Mathematics](https://books.google.it/books?id=vrQLbbxGNMsC&pg=PA197), Birkhäuser (2007), *sub voce*, but it seems to me that Kronecker never published his critique.

Comment: That is my impression too. But since here is a pool of professional historians maybe we can find out something.

Comment: There was a long discussion of it on [Math Forums](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=9986154):"*It is not found in Dauben's biography nor his paper... nor in either article by Schoenflies, nor in Bell's "Men of Mathematics"*". Well, if even E.T. Bell passed up on it we can be sure that it is a fake. They documented somewhat how it spread.